# Unable to push repo, large file

Tags: git, github

I accidentally added a large .eps file to my repo and was unable to push to github.

I've added the directory containing the file to .gitignore and tried running

```
git rm -rf --cached .
```

And then pushing the repo, but it's still giving me

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File 
Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 024db62abfc6a9ecb4771d5437bb9cdc
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File _assets/ToroAds_ChrisTuck.eps is 903.72 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Here is the contents of my .gitignore

```
/bower_components/
/node_modules/
/_assets/
```

Comment: Even if you remove the file from HEAD, it still exists in the commit. You need to change your history to remove it from the commit where it exists.

Comment: Did you try `git rm --cached file.eps`? This answer might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @kawnah doing that won't help because the file is already in the history of the branch. It has to be removed from the history, just as crashmstr is saying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)